# Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable in VSCode debugger

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, vscode-debugger

I'm testing Google Cloud Pub/Sub on my Django project using VSCode on my Mac, and I'm having some problems setting GCP environment variables during debugging tests, specifically the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

I am able to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` for running server and/or tests locally with `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/json_credential_file.json"` in a shell, but as the VSCode debugger runs in a separate shell the env variable is not set when debugging tests. I tried adding the same value to the `env` key in `launch.json`:

```
"env": {
    "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "path/to/json_credential_file.json"
}
```

But it still complains about GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS not being set:

```
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use launch configurations and set the "env" variable within the configuration specific to your programming language.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

```
"env": {
        "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "./secret.do.not.commit/serviceAccountTasks.privateKey.json"
      }
```

and here is the reference https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Answer (score 0):

in Powershell, run

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "path\serviceAccountTasks.privateKey.json", "User")`

This will set then env variable for all processes