# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS within java application?

Tags: java, google-text-to-speech

If I run `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=text-to-speech-key.json` in vscode terminal then everything works fine, but next time I open vscode I have to do it again. How can I get it to set in my Java program so it sets this when the program loads?

I tried setting it in my `.bash_profile` but that didn't work and it wouldn't seem useful since anyone using my app would not have that set up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set GOOGLE\_APPLICATION\_CREDENTIALS environment variable in VSCode debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58604780/set-google-application-credentials-environment-variable-in-vscode-debugger)

Comment: @Robert Harvey Surely that would only work in vscode, not for anyone else using my app?

Comment: @Robert Harvey At least it gets it working in vscode though, it's an improvement for sure.

Comment: Can you try this solution found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036472/google-cloud-texttospeech-java-io-ioexception-the-application-default-credent It appears you have similar concern